# /usr/bin/npm start works ok from command line, but getting memory error as systemctl service

Tags: node.js

When running command /usr/bin/npm start from command line, everything seems to be working fine.
I copied all files to /root and running it from that directory:

```
[root@dent-minitik01 ~]# pwd
/root
[root@dent-minitik01 ~]# /usr/bin/npm start

> minitik@1.0.0 start
> node index.js

Minitik server listening at https://minitik.dental.org.il/?code=0&id=305533168&providername=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C
```

However, when running  as systemctl I get error of Fatal javascript OOM in MemoryChunk allocation failed during deserialization.

The service is defined:

```
[root@dent-minitik01 ~]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/serverjs.service
[Unit]
Description=index.js

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start
Restart=on-failure
User=root
Group=root
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root
Environment=NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=1024
WorkingDirectory=/root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried changing NODE_OPTIONS up to 8GB - but I'm still getting the same error on systemctl start:

```
 serverjs.service - index.js
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/serverjs.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sun 2023-08-27 12:55:04 IDT; 4min 15s ago
  Process: 42731 ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start (code=dumped, signal=TRAP)
 Main PID: 42731 (code=dumped, signal=TRAP)
```

/var/log/messages shows:

```
kernel: traps: npm[42731] trap int3 ip:55cedf0d8756 sp:7ffc84f06800 error:0 in node[55cedd8e4000+2e61000]
Aug 27 12:55:04 dent-minitik01 npm[42731]: <--- Last few GCs --->
Aug 27 12:55:04 dent-minitik01 npm[42731]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
Aug 27 12:55:04 dent-minitik01 npm[42731]: #
Aug 27 12:55:04 dent-minitik01 npm[42731]: # **Fatal javascript OOM in MemoryChunk allocation failed during deserialization.**
Aug 27 12:55:04 dent-minitik01 npm[42731]: #
Aug 27 12:55:04 dent-minitik01 systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 42738/UID 0).
```

```
[root@dent-minitik01 ~]# npm -v
9.5.0 
[root@dent-minitik01 ~]# node -v 
v18.14.2
```

Comment: I edited and added the answer to my post.

Comment: Thanks. I already aswered. Maybe you need the line `After=network.target` in the [Unit] section of your service file. Additionally it could help to use nohup. Share the results of that approach if you want.

Comment: Thanks, but still getting the same.

Answer (score 1):

As you may need the `network.target` to be reached, try changing your service file to:

```
[Unit]
Description=index.js
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/npm start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can of course keep your additional settings.
This approach also uses nohup to keep npm / node running.

Comment: @OracleDBACurios Do you get the same error as before, or another one?

Comment: Yes, Still getting that same error Fatal javascript OOM in MemoryChunk allocation failed during deserialization. The strange thing it happens only when running from service. from command line it works ok

Comment: Did you try to remove the line `Environment=NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=1024` entirely from the service file and then start it?

Comment: @OracleDBACurios If that's not going to help, I would try to reinstall node and npm and then try again.

Comment: I will try, For now nothing works with this service

Comment: OK, after reinstalling all, also - more memory to the machine. it now works.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After reinstalling all, also - more memory to the machine which may have helped, it now works. Thank you